# Why have 2 values when i use query select in php?

Tags: php, select, pdo, duplicates

I'm newbie in PHP and when I use PHP to query select, I got 2 values, I realize it may be make slow if have 2 duplicated values.
So I want to ask about it and I also want to get just 1 values from select
thanks for reading my question.
here is picture:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code you have written?

Comment: Where is the code mate ?

Comment: I'm making a guess at the reason, please let me know if the code shows something else.

Comment: here my query: select id from char where id = 1292

Comment: i just get one row but get duplicate

Answer (score 0):

It dipends on what your i guess sql query respondes to your query. However if you want cut down your result in sql you can use LIMIT 1

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
WHERE   ...
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it's not, i just query one 1 id and get 2 id duplicate

Comment: as you see here: select id from char where id = 1292
i just select one id, but result is 2 same id